# Can't seem to change image position with key event

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, dom-events

I'm slowly learning some basic HTML 5 and Javascript. I wrote a Javascript file that's suppose to have an image displayed and then have the image's position changed by pressing right.  The image loads, but it doesn't it doesn't change position when I press right.  What am I doing wrong?

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 600;
canvas.style  = "border:2px solid blue";
canvas.addEventListener('keydown', doKeyDown, true);
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild( canvas );

var guy1Image = new Image();
guy1Image.onload = function () {
   ctx.drawImage( guy1Image, x, y );
};
guy1Image.src = "img/1.png";
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

function doKeyDown( e ) {
  if ( e.keyCode == 39 ) {
 x = 128;
     y = 128;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In key down  clear the canvas and redraw it again:)

```
   function doKeyDown( e ) {
      if ( e.keyCode == 39 ) {
         var canvas=document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
         var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
         ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, 800, 600 );
         x = 128;
         y = 128;
         ctx.drawImage( guy1Image, x, y );
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot focus on a canvas element, means your keydown event won't work. Here is a little work around for that

```
var lastDownTarget;
window.onload = function() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
        lastDownTarget = event.target;
        alert('mousedown');
    }, false);

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {console.log(lastDownTarget)
        if(lastDownTarget == canvas) {
            alert('keydown');
        }
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: It is not a complete solution to your answer, but you can use it with the solution given by Arun Kumar. hope it helps

Comment: +1 Good point. Actually you **can** get canvas to generate key events by assigning it a tabstop: canvas.setAttribute('tabindex','0');

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I tried to combine the solution, but it didn't seem to work. 

var lastDownTarget;
window.onload = function() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
        lastDownTarget = event.target;
        alert('mousedown');
    }, false);

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {console.log(lastDownTarget)
        if(lastDownTarget == canvas) {
         clearRect( 0, 0, 800, 600 );
         var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
         x = 128;
         y = 128;
         ctx.drawImage(guy1Image, x, y);
        }
    }, false);
}

Comment: it isn't working because "clearRect(0,0,800,600);" should be called on the canvas object like ctx.clearRect(0,0,800,600); and that too after you are declaring var ctx